# InitializationError while run cucumberRunner.java

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I got an below error while running cucumber Runner.java.  After analyzing the issue, I found that Cucumber.class is not run even though cucmber-junit-2.1.0 jar added in built path. Kindly help to resolve the below issue?

Error:
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate public [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9LeV.png)cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader) with [cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader@1e8b406]    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:44)    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:30)
[image]
Snap shots:

Comment: Can you post more of the error?

Comment: Log:-
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate public cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader) with [cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader@1e8b406]
at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:87)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:41)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:84)  at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:63)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use the *same version* for all of your Cucumber dependencies! (Or better yet, use dependency management like Maven or Gradle)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is classpath related. You also seem to have two different version of Cucumber in the classpath. Try different variations of your classpath, starting with just cucumber-junit and cucumber-core and see what you get.